# How to convert time format with fractal seconds in R

Tags: r, time-format

I am wondering how to convert time format that uses fractal seconds. I have a vector of time, that looks like the one presented on the screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2zoJ.jpg) (format is like "HHMMSSZZZ"). The data is of integer type. The task is to convert it to the normal time format.

Comment: It is a numeric column

Comment: You can try [anytime](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `strptime`

```
strptime(as.character(df1$TIME), format = "%I%M%OS")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(TIME = c(101323258, 101323258, 101323258, 101323259,
           101323260, 101323260, 101323261))
```